# How to maintain the order of the data in Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sequence, nsdictionary

I want to display the data in the sequence order. I am getting the json string as the response and converted into the Dictionary. I am not able to maintain the order after converted dictionary. 
I know it's not guaranteed the order when we use dictionary.
How do I maintain the actual order of the data.

Note: I can't hard code the key since data's are coming from the server response.

```
      func setupData(responseString : String)
      {
           // Convert string to dictionary for extracting the keys and values
           // Need to maintain the order while adding the data
           let content = convertToDictionary(text: responseString)
           var text : String = ""
           if let contentDataDict = content
           {
                 for (key, value) in  contentDataDict
                 {
                      // want to append the key and values in the sequence order
                        content +=  \(key) \n \(value)
                  }

            }
            textView.attributedText = text.htmlToAttributedString

     }
```

.

Comment: make an array of dictionaries instead and use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

You can not maintain order in the `Dictionary`.

## Long answer:

**Apple says:**

> Dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value associations.

Please refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

To maintain the order you need to use the `Array` or create `sorted` `Array`(Ascending, Descending or by using specific key) from the `Dictionary` and use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OrderedDictionary](https://swiftinit.org/reference/swift-collections/orderedcollections/ordereddictionary) from apple's [swift-collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) library.

You can add the depency in your `Package.swift` file like this:

```swift
dependencies: [
    // ...
    .package(
        url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-collections.git",
        from: "1.0.4"
    ),
    // ...
],
targets: [
    // ...
    .target(
        name: "App",
        dependencies: [
            .product(name: "Collections", package: "swift-collections"),
        ]
    ),
    // ...
]
```

Usage example:

```swift
import OrderedCollections

var orderedDict: OrderedDictionary<String, String> = [:]

orderedDict["B"] = "First Insertion"
orderedDict["C"] = "Second Insertion"
orderedDict["A"] = "Third Insertion"

print(orderedDict)
print(orderedDict)
print(orderedDict)
```

Output (*maintains order*):

```
[B: First Insertion, C: Second Insertion, A: Third Insertion]
[B: First Insertion, C: Second Insertion, A: Third Insertion]
[B: First Insertion, C: Second Insertion, A: Third Insertion]
```